# PGPlots xtick label from a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am trying to load data from a table which looks like below and use the 'label' column for `xticklabels`.

```
idx,label,value
1,20040101_20050108.rotation.summary, 19.470949839091155
2,20040101_20050115.rotation.summary, 3.2633743485078925
3,20040101_20050122.rotation.summary, 2.6505513476912275
4,20040101_20050129.rotation.summary, 1.8865512077042033
5,20040101_20050205.rotation.summary, 2.2793107344143277
```

I have around 600 rows and when I used `xtick=data` with `xticklabels from table={\mydata}{1}` I am getting a plot like below.

[image]

So I tried to use `xticklabel` customization like below with `\pgfplotstablegetelem`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmax=573,
    xticklabel={$\pgfplotstablegetelem{\tick}{1}\of{\mydata}$},
    xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=east}]
      \addplot[mark=none] table [
        x index={0},
        y index={2}] {\mydata};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But what I got was following:

[image]

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas to fix this.

**Update 1**

I figured out that I should use `\pgfplotsretval` to get the element value and updated my plot to reflect that like below

```
...
xticklabel={$\pgfplotstablegetelem{\tick}{label}\of{\mydata}\pgfplotsretval$},
...
```

But the label still has prefix added to the beginning of each label like `.000000002004010120061209.rotation.summary`.

**Update 2**

I found the solution. `xticklabel` should be something like below.

```
{
  \pgfmathparse{int(round(\tick))}
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfmathresult}{[index]1}\of{\stresscculogerr}\pgfplotsretval
}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Have you seen [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63335/pgfplots-using-strings-from-data-table-as-x-axis-labels-in-bar-chart)?

Comment: @Grimler, Thank you for your answer. I tried that. But it adds xtick labels for each tick. That doesn't work for me because I have around 600 data points. I just need to have labels for certain xticks as shown in above figures. Is there anyway that I can customized the linked answer to get xtick label outputs like I need.

Comment: as mentioned in my **Update 2**, I found the solution from [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283701/how-to-skip-ticks-in-pgfplots). Rounding the `\tick` made prefix go away.